# What's the easiest way to list all files opened by a program?

Tags: macos, debug

I'm debugging the initialization of a program (on a mac) and would I'd like to get a list of all the files opened during the execution, preferably in time order. Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fs_usage

And I need some more characters in this box, but I'm not sure what else to say...

Comment: This does what I want (although the -w option doesn't work).

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use [`lsof`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html).

Comment: I can use the lsof -r option, but there's no certainty that I'll get the whole set of files opened.

Comment: @eaubin: You might be able to use [`ktrace`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.4-intel/man1/ktrace.1.html).

Comment: Turns out ktrace isn't available on my machine, but dtrace can do it: 

sudo dtrace -s /dev/stdin

syscall::open*:entry
{
   printf("%s %s", execname, copyinstr(arg0));
}
Ctrl-D 

(from http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071031121823710)

Answer (score 3):

Fseventer gives a nice visual representation.

http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start&s[]=org